# Need Excel formula to return "Yes"/"No" instead of boolean

Tags: excel

I have this problem:  Write a formula (using the `OR` Function), that returns the following:

> if Column D = "Blue" OR Column E >=4 then "Yes", otherwise "No"

My solution returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. How can I get the function to return "yes" or "no"?

Comment: We can help you with your homework but expect to see what you've put together so far.

Comment: Do you actually want it to return yes or no or to you want a Boolean return to be formatted as yes or no? The advantage of the latter is that it's then easier to keep that cell as part of the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap it in an `IF`:

```
=IF(OR(D1="Blue",E1>=4),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: How about a combination formula. Can you help with that. 

It include the formula above and this one below?

Formula 1: Write a VLOOKUP formula that will return the value based on the output (Column D) 

column a.Category row 1=Red column b. Value=2 column d.output=Blue